# add properties to gst_video_convert_sample()

Tags: gstreamer

I am attempting to capture a jpeg snapshot from a stream, much like the 
example listed here: 
https://github.com/rubenrua/GstreamerCodeSnippets/blob/master/C/takepic.c

It actually works but I am unable to pass the jpegenc "quality" property:

```
GstCaps *caps; 
GstSample *from_sample, *to_sample; 
caps = gst_caps_from_string("image/jpeg, quality=99"); //doesn't work!
to_sample = gst_video_convert_sample (from_sample, caps, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, &err);
```

Please help

Comment: The `quality` options is not part of the caps, but a property of the specific jpegenc element. So would need to access the `jpegenc` element from your pipeline and set this property on that one via `g_object_set()`.

Comment: Florian, as you can see in the link to takepic above, no jpegenc element appears in the pipeline. Actually there is no pipeline at all. this is used to generate the jpeg: to_sample = **gst_video_convert_sample (from_sample, caps, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, &err);**

Comment: You need to modify that code. It looks up the encoder depending on your caps. `encoder = get_encoder (to_caps, &error);` Here an encoder has been found and is added to the pipeline. If you want it to have special properties, here is a good place to set them.

Comment: I'm referring to this code: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/blob/master/gst-libs/gst/video/convertframe.c . It is a small helper. As it is right now, it does not support what you want it to do without modifications to it.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I already looked at this cod eand thought appsrc and appsink would do.